# Html.BeginForm and HTML Attributes w/o specifying Controller and Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.beginform

I like the cleanliness of

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
```

And hate that adding HTML attributes requires specifying the controller, action, and form method.

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post,
  new { id = "inactivate-form" })
```

Is there a way to use `Html.BeginForm` and specify HTML attributes for the form without manually wiring everything else up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why would you not just use plain html?

```
<form id="inactivate-form" method="post" >
</form>
```

Comment: this is exactly what new users of ASP.NET MVC need to understand. It doesn't have to be all code. :)

Comment: No reason other than trying to follow examples. I prefer your suggested method to `Html.BeginForm`.

@CodeMonkey how could you tell I am a new user of ASP.NET MVC? :)

Comment: Actually I found the hard way that if you don't use BeginForm you will not get the client-side validation to work as it will not get "hooked up" otherwise.

Comment: @Philippe how are you emitting your c-side validation

Comment: Unobtrusive validation will only work if the form was surrounded by the 'using(BeginForm())' method.

Comment: @JasonWicker I think this is only if you're using the Microsoft Ajax library - but the MVC approach doesn't add that extra markup

Answer (score 12):

You could create a custom extension that adds an 'Id-ed' form:

```
public static MvcForm BeginIdedForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string id)
{
    return htmlHelper.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "id", id } });
}
```

Usage then just becomes

```
using(Html.BeginIdedForm("inactiveate-form"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [@nick-olsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7796198/61654) use `null` for the action/controller parameters:

```
@Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object>() {{ "id", id }}
```

The `BeginForm` method eventually calls `System.Web.Mvc.RouteValuesHelpers.MergeRouteValues` which looks up the action and controller names from the `RequestContext.RouteData` if they're `null` posting back to the same action/controller as the form was created from.